# bash + convert text file to csv file

Tags: bash, csv, perl, awk, sed

we have the following file - `info.txt`

the file include the name of **Linux machine** and the relevant parameters for each Linux-name and values

```
more info.txt

LINUX_NAME=linux_machine_1
param.avarge.com 3443
param.no.com 43
param.lol.com 54
param.tis.com 24
param.er.com 254
param.nh.com 13
param.pl.com 456
param.nm.com 534
param.asd.com 236
LINUX_NAME=linux_machine_2
param.avarge.com 12
param.no.com 1
param.lol.com 2
param.tis.com 3
param.er.com 254
param.nh.com 13
param.pl.com 456
param.nm.com 534
param.asd.com 236
LINUX_NAME=linux_machine_3
param.avarge.com 13
param.no.com 100
param.lol.com 101
param.tis.com 102
param.er.com 254
param.nh.com 13
param.pl.com 456
param.nm.com 534
param.asd.com 236

.
.
.
```

we want to convert the `info.txt` to csv file as the following

expected results

```
PARAMETER,param.avarge.com,param.no.com,param.lol.com,param.tis.com,param.er.com,param.nh.com,param.pl.com,param.nm.com,param.asd.com
linux_machine_1,3443,43,54,24,254,13,456,534,236
linux_machine_2,12,1,2,3,254,13,456,534,236
linux_machine_3,13,100,101,102,254,13,456,534,236
.
.
.
```

.

any suggestions how to perform it with `bash,awk/sed, perl one liner`

example how it should be from csv file

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Could a parameter be missing? Or come in a different order?

Comment: parameter never missing and no different order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works under the assumption the list of hosts per machine is identical (and in the same order) over all machines.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @machines;

while (<>)
{
    if ( / LINUX_NAME = (.+) /x )
    {
        push @machines, { name => $1, hosts => [] };
    } 
    else
    {
        chomp;
        my ( $host, $port ) = split / /;
        push @{ $machines[-1]->{hosts} }, { host => $host, port => $port };
    }
}

print join( ",", "PARAMETER", map { $_->{host} } @{ $machines[-1]->{hosts} } ), "\n";

foreach my $machine ( @machines )
{
    print join( ",", $machine->{name}, map { $_->{port} } @{ $machine->{hosts} } ), "\n";
}
```